# Speeded-Up Robust Features SURF

Tags: computer-vision, surf

I'm implementing SURF algorithm and I'm referring to the Chris Evan's OpenSURF .

In OpenSURF and in almost all the other SURF implementations I see that when Dxx and Dyy are computed a multiplying factor 3 is used(look at the code below). No where in the SURF paper or OpenSURF paper is it mentioned why they do it. I have no problem in doing the same but I'm curious to know why this multiplication is being carried out. If it is important for the Dxx and Dyy computations then why is it not mentioned anywhere? Am I missing it?
Can anyone having experience with this give me some explanation?
Regards

```
Dxx and Dyy along with Dxy are used to calculate the Determinant
Dxx = BoxIntegral(img, r - l + 1, c - b, 2*l - 1, w)
          - BoxIntegral(img, r - l + 1, c - l / 2, 2*l - 1, l)*3; // Why 3 here?

Dyy = BoxIntegral(img, r - b, c - l + 1, w, 2*l - 1)
          - BoxIntegral(img, r - l / 2, c - l + 1, l, 2*l - 1)*3; // Why 3 here?
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Posting empty "bump" questions is no way to attract attention to your other questions. Consider changing the wording of your question, or perhaps adding more detail or changing the tags. If nothing else works, consider adding some bounty (though you need to earn enough reputation to be able to do it). Good luck!

Comment: Ok, sorry
Is that illegal here ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You should refer to the [updated paper](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/ReadingSeminar/Papers/Bay08.pdf) published in 2008 that provides additional details, in particular regarding the box filter lobes properties.*

If you refer to section 3.2 and figure 2, you can see that the central lobe (black one) of the box filter has a negative factor of `-2` while the white lateral lobes have a positive factor of `+1`.

With the above formulas the factor `3` is simply related to the fact that, thanks to the integral image:

- you sum `+1` over the whole area,
- then you perform a subtraction (with `-3`) over the central lobe only

This gives you the `-2` expected factor for the central lobe (`1 - 3`).